# Im getting java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy java client

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to call the external SOAP endpoint, But I'm getting this error
[image]

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy
```

I tried to resolve this by adding the `sun.web.xml` file and so on but no luck. Using Tomact 9 with JDK8-correctto .

tried with addig file named: /META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider with the following contents:

org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl

#Update
adding  to the sun-web.xml file. NO LUCK

Comment: What did you do and try before posting here? Please summarize your findings.

Comment: @JustLudo added Inside the aforementioned JAR there is a file named: /META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider with the following contents:

org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl

Comment: I think you need to post more relevant information here. Something like the code that calls the soap endpoint and maybe the way this was setup. From where you are running and what process triggers this. If you are using middleware or some platform to configure, please mention them here as well (including tags if there are tags for it). Right now we can only guess what is happening.

Comment: @JustLudo added more information

Comment: What program is calling this? Is it custom made?

Comment: @JustLudo yes calling 3rd party SOAP endpoint